# Creating HTML Input based calculator

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to create an html input based calculator, it just keeps returning *This is a snippet added on later, but How would i do this in jQuery *

[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

so heres my code

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
        <input id="nume" type="number">
        <input id="num" type="number">
        <input type="button" onclick="MyFunction()" value="Click to calculate">
        <p id="f">Value Is: 0</p>
</body>
<script>
    const something = document.getElementById("nume")
    const somethingElse = document.getElementById("num")
    function MyFunction(){
    var values = something + somethingElse;
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML = "Value Is: " + values
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: You are currently trying to add the html elements together instead of the input's value, use their `.value` property to get the value. Note though it will be a string so you have to convert it first to a number otherwise you will be concatenating strings instead of adding numbera

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you need to get value first. `document.getElementById("nume").value` You can do it this way

```js
    function MyFunction(){
    var values = Number(document.getElementById("nume").value) + Number(document.getElementById("num").value);
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML = "Value Is: " + values
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
        <input id="nume" type="number">
        <input id="num" type="number">
        <input type="button" onclick="MyFunction()" value="Click to calculate">
        <p id="f">Value Is: 0</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Number(document.getElementById("nume").value)` to get the actual number. by just using `document.getElementById("nume")` you are getting the HTML DOM element and not the element's value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly your code has the two variables which should be inside the function
2. Secondly to access the value attribute of `<input>`
3. thirdly I got number as string so i converted form string to number using Number();

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="nume" type="number"><br/>
    <input id="num" type="number"><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="MyFunction()" value="Click to calculate"><br/>
    <p id="f">Value Is: 0</p>
</body>
<script>
    function MyFunction(){
      var something=document.getElementById("nume").value;
      var somethingElse = document.getElementById("num").value;
      document.getElementById("f").innerHTML=Number(something)+Number(somethingElse);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct at your end just need few updates...

```html
<!--<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
        <input id="nume" type="number">
        <input id="num" type="number">
        <input type="button" onclick="MyFunction()" value="Click to calculate">
        <p id="f">Value Is: 0</p>
</body>
<script>
    const something = document.getElementById("nume")
    const somethingElse = document.getElementById("num")
    function MyFunction(){
    var values = something + somethingElse;
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML = "Value Is: " + values
    }
    
</script>-->

<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
        <input id="nume" type="number">
        <input id="num" type="number">
        <input type="button" onclick="MyFunction()" value="Click to calculate">
        <p id="f">Value Is: 0</p>
</body>
<script>
    const something = document.getElementById("nume")
    const somethingElse = document.getElementById("num")
    function MyFunction(){
    var values = parseFloat(something.value) + parseFloat(somethingElse.value);
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML = "Value Is: " + values
    }
    
</script>
```

You can use given code...which is not commented over here.
That is because the statement

```
const something = document.getElementById("num")
```

will return an **html element** in **document** with the id that you have given in **() rounded brackets** so if you are making an calculator you can use this statement...

```
something.value
```

because it will return the **string value** which is stored inside the **html element** in **document** with the id that you have given in **() rounded brackets**....now the problem is that you want to add those right?

so just use the math function **parseFloat** like this...

```
var values = parseFloat(something.value) + parseFloat(somethingElse.value);
```

so that you can cast them to float ... you can use **parseInt** also but i suggest to use the above statement..Now you can make a calculator easily...

Isn't it right? :)

Comment: How would you do this in jQuery? Thank you very much for the answers by the way

Comment: Hey there, @RandomCodingWords thanks fro appreciate. I would like to answer your question ... that **How would you do this in jQuery?** ...It is that simple you just need to download library first, then set up all paths for javaScript and then...you need to use `const something = $("#num");` same as for input field "somethingElse" (i.e. replace "#num" with "#nume" in above line) the for adding you can use the same statement as mentioned above...now for showing result you must use... `$("#f").text("Value is : "+values);` I hope it will be helpful.